# public variables wp7 mango

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

hi i need to use a variables from page to show in another page at text block in windows phone 7. i got a problem that the second page doesn't declare the variables: here's a part of my  code:

```
public static class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string result;//var i wanna use at the all application pages
    string status;//var i wanna use at the all application pages
    string userId;//var i wanna use at the all application pages
    string msg;//var i wanna use at the all application pages

    WebClient client;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }
}

///second page
public partial class info : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public info()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBlock1.Text = result.value();
    }
}
```

but this code dosent work  ny help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but this code dosent work

Because your variables are **private** and their scope is limited to the `MainPage` class.

If you want them to be public, you have to add the `public` keyword.

Better: you should use properties instead:

```
public string Result { get; set; }
```

---

Also, you can't write a *global variable*. As C# is an object-oriented programming language, you'll have to use an instance of your `MainPage` class to access to your properties:

```
MainPage myPage = new MainPage();
....
textBlock1.Text = myPage.Result;
```

---

Another thing: you're using variables/properties, not functions. So you can't write `result.value();`. Use `result.value;` instead.

I suggest you to have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) about properties.

Comment: ok thanx alot.. but i found another problem the result value  doesnt appear at textblock at info page.. i wanna got it from a web service i declared it at main page class ...could be this is the problem?!

Comment: @ワラNawras Hum, in order to make things clear and because your problem is related to something different than variables scope, I suggest you to ask another question about your new problem. You should also post all the code related to your web service call.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to declare result variable outside the MainPage class scope or add public keyword